# Fetching the list of all "Activated" and "Not Activated" Windows servers

Tags: windows, batch-file

I am trying to write a script, where from a list of servers, upon execution of the script, displays the number of servers where windows is "Licensed" or "Not Licensed". I have written this script, but the problem is, the servers which are not activated also gives the output as "Licensed".

Here is the Script -

```
@echo off

Set RESULTFILE=C:\users\v7t7adm\desktop\result.txt

Set SERVERLIST=C:\users\v7t7adm\desktop\server.txt

:START-SCRIPT
@for /F "tokens=1-10 delims=" %%a in ('type %SERVERLIST%') do (

Set SERVERNAME=%%a
Call :SCRIPT

)

:SCRIPT

@for /F "tokens=1-10 delims=:" %%a in ('cscript c:\Windows\System32\slmgr.vbs %SERVERNAME% /dli ^| findstr /I /C:"License Status:"') do Set STATUS=%%b

Call :ECHO-RESULT

Goto :EOF

:ECHO-RESULT

IF %STATUS% neq "Licensed " set %STATUS% = "Not Licensed"

echo %SERVERNAME% - %STATUS% >> %RESULTFILE%

echo %SERVERNAME% - %STATUS%

Goto :EOF
```

When I remotely run "cscript c:\Windows\System32\slmgr.vbs %SERVERNAME% /dli" on the server which is not activated, it gives an output as -

**Connected to server x**

**(blank)**

The desired output is -

server x - Not Licensed

server y - Licensed

But i am getting the output -

server x - Licensed

server y - Licensed

Comment: Since the output is empty, the value of `%STATUS%` isn't being changed and is just reporting the previous server's status.  Add `set STATUS=NONE` or similar before the `for` command to set a default value.

Comment: @HarryJohnston for that reason, I tried with the server which is "Not Activated" as the first  server in the list, so that there are no redundancies.

Comment: Unless you open a new command window, the variable might still be set from previous runs of the script.

Comment: Note also that there mustn't be a space between the variable name and the equals sign in a `set` command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some tips:

- if you use `"delims="` there is only one token for the whole input line, one token is the default.
- If there is only one server per line and the server name can't contain spaces there is no need to define delims.
- if the file name contains no spaces (and isn't in UTF) you don't need to `type` the file
- if you call a subroutine you can pass an argument, no need to store in vars then.
- if you parse slmgr.vbs output splitting at the colon, there will be space(s) in front of the License Status, so either trim or compare with these spaces.
- when comparing var content with a string in qoutes you'll also have to quote the var content.
- When setting a var don't use `Set %varname%=content`, this creates a new var with var's content as name.
- while debugging use an open cmd window and temporily set echo on

Having a different locale I can't test the text `" Licensed"`

```
@echo off
Set "RESULTFILE=C:\users\v7t7adm\desktop\result.txt"
Set "SERVERLIST=C:\users\v7t7adm\desktop\server.txt"
Set "SlMgr=cscript c:\Windows\System32\slmgr.vbs"

:START-SCRIPT
@for /F %%a in (%SERVERLIST%) do Call :SCRIPT %%a
Goto :eof

:SCRIPT
Set "STATUS="
@for /F "tokens=1-2 delims=:" %%a in (
  '%SlMgr% %1 /dli ^|findstr /I /C:"License Status:"'
) do Set STATUS=%%b

IF not defined STATUS Echo couldn't evaluate License status for %1 &Goto :Eof

IF /I "%STATUS%" neq " Licensed" set "STATUS=Not Licensed"

echo %1 - [%STATUS%]
echo %1 - [%STATUS%] >> %RESULTFILE%

Goto :EOF
```

Comment: Everything is working fine, but when i run this script over the entire environment, it still gives wrong results.

Comment: Are there non English locales? Slmgr.vbs will return localized strings.

Comment: Please elaborate?

Comment: Sorry wrong track. Reading on my phone I didn't see the whole batch. You will need to find out yourself what the differences result from.